# Merged feature branch into master - continue working on feature branch with new master changes?

Tags: git, version-control

I have the following scenario:

1. `git checkout feature_branch`
2. Did some work on `feature_branch`
3. In the meantime, `master` was updated with things that I want to have in `feature_branch` as well
4. Pushed changes in `feature_branch` to `origin`
5. `git checkout master && git pull && git merge fr_1285`

Now master is up to date and has all my changes in it (I'm not sure this is exactly what I wanted, though).

From this point, how can I continue working on my own (already pushed) `feature_branch` using the updated files in `master`? Have I already screwed up?

Comment: Sounds like you should perform an uplift to master by merging feature branch with master and push the merge to feature branch. Then continue working after the merge..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First commit the changes to the feature branch, then do `git checkout origin master` prior to do a `git pull` to the master (you will have all the codebase in the origin master up to date). Then you can merge the feature branch to the master branch by:

```
git merge feature_branch
```

You need to finalize with a `git push origin master` to have all the changes from future branch included in the master branch.

You can continue your work on the feature branch by checking out.

```
git checkout feature_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all your changes from master to feature _branch by rebasing feature_branch onto master